# Can you change the width of div in container?

Tags: html, css

I have a popup inside a container which has a certain width (about 60% of the site). My Question would be if is it possible to make my popup 100% width. Without moving the div outside of the container.

If not possible I'll have to find a workaround.

At the moment I only accomplish that when moving the div outside of the container but then the popup is at the top of the page.

Comment: B  could please create a code snippet

Comment: You need to provide code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `width: calc()` and a bit of maths (if your outer container is 60% I guess your inner would have to be 166.6667%, assuming it's a direct child, and not taking padding, margin etc into account), but it might be easier to use `width: 100vw`, which should make it 100% of the viewport width.

Comment: Thank you very much the width:100vw worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If the container is not positioned, then you could set `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;` on your popup, and be happy.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xhmg6vha/

Answer (score 0):

You can position the div with `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`. Then you can place the popup related to your window reference as `top:0, left:0`.